# Cannot run Hive Queries - Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am attempting to run some basic Hive queries. The hive shell opens OK but when I attempt to run any commands I get the following error:

```
FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

My hive-site.xml file looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
-->

<configuration>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>controls whether to connect to remove metastore server or open a new metastore server in Hive Client JVM</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:${DBPROTO}://${DBHOST}/${DBNAME}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>${DBDRIVER}</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>${DBUSER}</value>
  <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>${DBPASSWD}</value>
  <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>${WHDIR}</value>
  <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
    <value>${SASL_ENABLED}</value>
    <description>If true, the metastore thrift interface will be secured with SASL. Clients must authenticate with Kerberos.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file</name>
  <value>${KEYTAB_PATH}</value>
  <description>The path to the Kerberos Keytab file containing the metastore thrift server's service principal.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>${KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL}</value>
  <description>The service principal for the metastore thrift server. The special string _HOST will be replaced automatically with the correct host name.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes</name>
  <value>Table,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order</value>
  <description>List of comma separated metastore object types that should be pinned in the cache</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://${METASTORE_SERVER}:${METASTORE_PORT}</value>
  <description>URI for client to contact metastore server</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.semantic.analyzer.factory.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hive.hcatalog.cli.HCatSemanticAnalyzerFactory</value>
  <description>controls which SemanticAnalyzerFactory implementation class is used by CLI</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout</name>
  <value>60</value>
  <description>MetaStore Client socket timeout in seconds</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
<value>false</value>
<description/>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Is there some configuration in the above file that I am missing? I have moved the JDBC connection jar into the lib folder and attempted a few other fixes but I cannot get past this point.

Comment: That error message is useless. There should be a more meaningful error message lower in the stack, under a _`caused by`_ entry.

Comment: _"The hive shell opens OK "_ > which shell? the legacy, deprecated `hive` fat client, or the `beeline` JDBC thin client?

Comment: Which version of Hive are you using by the way?

Comment: If the xml literally has ${value} things, that needs fixed